# Validation on textbox VBA Word prevents button click executing

Tags: vba, validation, ms-word, textbox

I am working on a Word template that has 5 text boxes on a user form (frmMain).

I have a validation routine for each text box, that checks if the correct format is used (i.e. date format in one text box, only allowing the use of numeric values in another, preventing all text boxes left empty and so on). One of my text boxes is called txtNumber.

As of now, one of the validation sub routine fires on txtNumber_Exit.

I also have a command button (cmdHelp) on the same user form that, when clicked, fires the sub routine that shows another user form (frmHelp) that contains a help text on how to use this template.

My problem is that when I click this command button (cmdHelp), the validation routine for the text box "txtNumber" fires. Hence I am stuck with a message (written by me) in a msgbox that says "Number can not be blank", and the frmHelp is not showing.

After this, none of my text boxes have the focus, but my cmdHelp button does.
So if I click the cmdHelp button now, the frmHelp is correctly showing.

But this is messing up the workflow, making the visual experience a bit fuzzy for the user, given the fact that the user gets unnecessary info on invalid input in the txtNumber text box, and that the user needs to click twice on the cmdHelp button.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Add code to your cmdHelp button to set your txtNumber TextBox .Enabled = False, then to reset it to True again after your cmdHelp window is closed.

Comment: @macropod: The cursor is in the text box txtNumber. When I click the cmdHelp button, the sub txtNumber_Exit fires BEFORE any code written for the sub cmdHelp_Click. So this is in my opinion not possible, given my code at the moment.
Can I put my validation in another sub/event handler?